# Transformations.switchMap - Как при повороте устройства не делать запрос к базе данных повторно?

Tags: android, livedata

[image: Страница из книги]

Этот момент ввел в ступор, а в частности такое предложение

> Так как для этого требуется поиск по базе данных, который вы не хотите без необходимости **повторять при повороте устройства**.

А дальше код в **viewModel** с использованием **Transformations.switchMap**. В **onCreate** методе фрагмента вызывается **loadCrime** в который передается **crimeId**.

> Используйте LiveData для реализации отношений, при которых изменение идентификатора преступления вызывает новый запрос к базе данных

Как я понял запрос произойдет только если изменится идентификатор? Но на практике всё совсем иначе, при повороте фрагмент уничтожается и снова в методе **onCreate** вызывается **loadCrime**. Передается тот же id но происходит запрос к базе данных. Почему так? Это ошибка в книге? Значит что присвоение такого же значения считается за обновление данных? Тогда же теряется весь смысл использования **Transformations.switchMap**

Comment: Подозреваю, что код относится только к первому абзацу, switchMap просто преобразует LiveData<UUID> в LiveData<Crime>. Про повороты устройства наверняка будет код далее, в частности loadCrime должен вызываться только при пустом savedInstanceState...

Comment: @YuraIvanov в том то и дело что дальше ничего про это нет. Далее идёт про сохранение данных в базу в методе **onStop**. Походу это действительно косяк в книге

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кто нибудь задастся тем же вопросом то знайте, что в книге "Андроид программирование для профессионалов" Кристин Марсикано, Брайан Гарднер и т.д, в 12 главе в разделе **Преобразование LiveData** опущен очень важный момент. Как и отметил Yura Ivanov в комментарии под вопросом, в **onCreate** необходимо добавить условие

```
if (savedInstanceState == null)
    viewModel.loadCrime(crimeId)
```

Ни в самой книге ни в примерах кода которые можно загрузить с сайта указанного в самой книге нет упоминания про это, мало того в примере кода в методе **onViewCreated** идет дублирование строк

```
val crimeId = arguments?.getSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID) as UUID
viewModel.loadCrime(crimeId)
```

После этого при смене конфигурации(повороте устройства) не будет осуществляться повторный запрос к базе данных